# Why difference between the local and remote repository is not the same as committed?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a merge conflict and the first thing I wanted to see is what is the difference between the local and remote versions of the file. For that I have executed the following:

```
git diff origin:path/to/my/file.py path/to/my/file.py
```

This way I saw that my local version has some additional blocks.

Then I wanted to see what exactly did I commit. So I have executed:

```
git diff --staged path/to/my/file.py
```

Surprisingly to me I saw another block of changes that is not the same as the block returned by the previous command.

I have opened my file in a text editors and saw both blocks. Now I do not know how to interpret it.

It looks like there is a difference between the local and remote versions and this difference is not the one that I have committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you expect those diffs to be the same in the first place.

Remember that `origin:path/to/my/file.py` refers to the version of `path/to/my/file.py` extracted from the commit to which `origin` resolves, which is generally `origin/HEAD`, which is generally `origin/master`.  The `git diff` command will then compare that file, extracted from that commit, to whatever is in your work-tree right now, which—if you're resolving a merge conflict—will generally be the version with conflict markers surrounding the conflict.

#### Aside: `git diff`

Note that running `git diff` during a merge conflict likes to try to show *combined diffs*.  But running `git diff <commit-specifier>:<path> <path>` avoids that.  Meanwhile, running `git diff --staged <path>` just says:

```
$ git diff --staged path/to/file
* Unmerged path path/to/file
```

(unless you have `git add`ed a version of `path/to/file` from the work-tree, to tell Git that you have correctly merged the file already, in which case it compares the `HEAD` version to the one you copied into the index by `git add`ing).

#### What `git merge` is doing

That's not what `git merge` is looking at and merging.  What `git merge` is looking at is *two* diffs:

- One diff is from your merge base, whichever commit that is, to `HEAD`.
- The second diff is from your merge base to your other head, whichever commit that is (maybe `origin/master`, maybe not).

You can obtain these two diffs by first obtaining the merge base commit hash.  Let's say, to simplify things, you ran `git merge origin/master` and are now looking at a merge conflict on `path/to/my/file.py`.  Your Git has first run:

```
git merge-base --all HEAD origin/master
```

With any luck, this produces just one commit hash ID.<sup>1</sup>  You can save that in a variable:

```
base=$(git merge-base --all HEAD origin/master)
```

and then use it in the two specific diffs:

```
git diff $base HEAD -- path/to/my/file.py           # what git thinks I changed
git diff $base origin/master -- path/to/my/file.py  # what git thinks they changed
```

If you want to compare all three files directly, you can extract them into temporaries.  This is what `git mergetool` does, for instance: it extracts the base `path/to/my/file.py`, the local (HEAD) file, and the other ("remote head") file, from each of these three commits, and then runs your chosen merge tool on all three files.

---

If `git merge-base --all` produces more than one hash ID, your `git merge -s recursive` did an internal merge of all of those commits, committed the result as a temporary commit, and is using *that* commit's hash as the merge base.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your changes were staged, others weren't. Both of those are showed by the first command. The second shows only those changes which were staged.

Please execute:

```
git add path/to/my/file.py
```

Then `git diff --staged` will show the same output as the first command.

Comment: The first command does not show the both changes. The two commands show two different changes in my case.

Comment: When I execute "git diff" on my file I get nothing. So, I guess all the chanegs for this file are staged. This is why I think that I do not need to execute "git add".

Comment: `git status` will show you that your changes are in the section "Changes to be commited". Plain `git diff` shows only changes in files mentioned in "Changes not staged for commit".